# SQ Lite Using LIKE Function to find two or three words only

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

How would I use the LIKE function to extract rows with a city name of two or three words. e.g. New York

Basically voiding all city names that contain one word. e.g. London

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that spaces would only occur in between parts of a city name, then the following simple query should do:

```sql
SELECT city_name
FROM yourTable
WHERE city_name LIKE '% %';
```

For detecting more than two words, we can "count" the number of spaces to figure out how many words are present:

```sql
SELECT city_name
FROM yourTable
WHERE LENGTH(city_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(city_name, ' ', '')) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `% %` for the spaces between the words.
The query should be like;

```
SELECT
    city_name
FROM
    cities
WHERE
    city_name LIKE '% %';
```

Comment: Another user gave this answer 5 minutes before you posted.